# How can i put color on text in lua?

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

```
currentHead, maximumHead= GetInventoryItemDurability(1);
currentShoulder, maximumShoulder = GetInventoryItemDurability(3);
currentChest, maximumChest = GetInventoryItemDurability(5);

print("Head: " .. currentHead .. " Durability")
print("Shoulders: " .. currentShoulder .. " Durability")
print("Chest: " .. currentChest .. "/" .. maximumChest .. " Durability")
```

I am making an addon for the game World of Warcraft , and i would like to know how can i change the color of the letters in print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. If found it via websearch within a minute or so...

https://www.wowinterface.com/forums/showthread.php?t=25712

```
colors = {
    {
        title = 'LIGHTBLUE',
        color = 'cff00ccff',
    }, -- and many more
}
function printColors()
    --print("\124cffFF0000This text is red\124r") --This is red color
    local startLine = '\124'
    local endLine = '\124r'
    for i = 1, table.getn(colors) do
        print(startLine .. colors[i].color .. colors[i].title .. endLine)
    end
end
```

According to
https://wow.gamepedia.com/UI_escape_sequences

you can also use `WrapTextInColorCode(text, colorCode)`

Comment: Which Lua version has ```table.getn()```? - And what can be a replacement in Lua 5.3 for ```table.getn()```?

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi getn was deprecated in Lua 5.1. use the length operator `#`,  `#colors` replaces `table.getn(colors)`. or simply do `for i,v in ipairs(colors) do print( startLine .. v.color .. v.title .. endline) end` do you have websearch where you live?

Comment: I am from Berlin/Germany and i use metager.de - I tried the code above in Lua 5.3.5 with ```lua -i``` replacing ```table.getn()``` with ```#colors``` and no colored output happens - Only weird code like: ```|cff00ccffLIGHTBLUE|r```

Comment: I wasn't aware WoW is already on Lua 5.3.5, I can only tell you what is in the documentation I found and what I have confirmed with several examples in forums. if that doesn't work you're probably better off asking in the WoW community

Comment: Agreed - Sorry for my fail

Comment: Sounds like you're evaluating the code outside of the game - the |c escape sequence to apply color will only work when used within WoW, it's not a general Lua feature.